# How can i update a row in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, datatable, sql-update

i have a table named person and it looks like this:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE public.person
(
"idPerson" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('idperson'::regclass),
fname character varying(45) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
lname character varying(45) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
sex character(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
dateofbirth date,
address character varying(75) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
city character varying(45) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
country character varying(45) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
CONSTRAINT "idPerson_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("idPerson")
)
```

I want to perform an update through a function( my_update_function(fname,lname , sex ,dateofbirth,address,city,country)  . My problem here is that i dont want a specific condition ,instead i want to just call the function like this for example:

```
SELECT my_update_function('Jamie','Phillips', 'F',1973-03-08,'Santina Island 108','Okhotsk',Russia)
```

and updates my table in the row with idPerson 57 only in the column that it is different (fname in this case )

This is what i did:

```
        UPDATE person 
    SET fname=my_update_function.fname , lname=my_update_function.lname
        ,sex=my_update_function.sex , dateofbirth=my_update_function.dateofbirth
        ,address=my_update_function.address , city=my_update_function.city
        ,country=my_update_function.country
    WHERE person.fname='Karissa';
```

I updated my table but the problem here is that i had to put the specific fname 'Karissa' inside of the function ,instead i want to be done automatically .

How can i do something like that?

Thank you.

Comment: In your desired automazed function, where does the name `Karissa` come from?

Comment: What is the condition to locate the record you want to update? In the example of `my_update_function` you don't specify idPerson. According to your table definition there are no unique constraints/indeces to identify the record using other fields. Please explain what the function `my_update_function` should do using parameters it accepts.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe If you check the table above you will see a person with the name Karissa . It was just a try to check how the update function should work

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis I was asked to crate a function that takes (fname,lname,sex,dateofbirth,address, city,country ) as input parameters. As i can understand i should call my_update_function to make the updates i want . For example if i call it like this : my_update_function('Jamie','Phillips','F',1973-03-08,'Santina Island 108','Okhotsk',Russia) should find  which row i want to update and then change it . In case for example ,i want to update the name ,the sex and the country i guess my function should find the person i want to based on the other paramaters that stay the same

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis As far as idPerson is concerned that is a primary key , my professor said that i should not use it as a parameter in the update function

Comment: @Gn gnk I guess your professonr has a good reason (I just don't know it). Any way - to update a specific record you must specify it. No matter - primary key or other unique constraint, there should be some criteria to identify the record you tell the function to update.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this

```
execute 'UPDATE person 
SET fname='||my_update_function.fname||' , lname='||my_update_function.lname||'
    ,sex='||my_update_function.sex||' , dateofbirth='||my_update_function.dateofbirth||'
    ,address='||my_update_function.address||' , city='||y_update_function.city||'
    ,country='||my_update_function.country||'
WHERE person.fname='''||my_update_function.fname||'''';
```

or (better, because it is not vulnerable to SQL injection)

```
prepare query as UPDATE person SET fname=$1 , lname=$2 ,sex=$3, dateofbirth=$4,address=$5, city=$6,country=$7 WHERE person.fname=$8;
execute query(fname,lname,sex,dateofbirth,address,city,country,fname);
```

Comment: If you use quote_literal(), there can't have sql injection anymore.

`prepare query as UPDATE person SET fname=$1 , lname=$2 ,sex=$3, dateofbirth=$4,address=$5, city=$6,country=$7 WHERE person.fname=$8;`
`execute query(quote_literal(fname), quote_literal(lname), sex,dateofbirth,address,city,country,fname);`